# How to avoid full rebuild when changing RUSTFLAGS?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

In Rust, switching back and forth between `debug` and `release` builds doesn't trigger a full rebuild. I'd like something similar for changing `RUSTFLAGS`.

I usually suppress some compiler warnings during development. It helps me focus, I fix them once the feature is complete.

`RUSTFLAGS=-A dead_code -A unused_variables -A unused_mut -A unused_imports`

However, running `cargo check` (or `cargo fix`) forces a full rebuild for all crates. I assume it's due to changes in `RUSTFLAGS`. And when I execute `cargo run` after `cargo check`, there is a full rebuild, again.

Is there a way to avoid that? Maybe cache the build results or only use those `RUSTFLAGS` for select crates?

Even restarting the IDE (CLion with Rust plugin) forces a full rebuild. And I have to turn off the otherwise very useful Cargo Check background task because it slows down builds too much.

Comment: I think changing the profile does cause a rebuild.

Comment: You can try defining a [custom profile](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#custom-profiles) and set your `RUSTFLAGS` in this profile. This should build into a folder named after your profile in `target`, and so avoid a full rebuild when switching back and forth.

Comment: `cargo rustc -- -A dead_code` correctly uses the already-built crates, but I don't think you can use that to disable warnings for CLion+Rust.

Comment: I would also advise just using `#![allow(...)]` attributes on your crate during development and removing them at the end. These don't cause a full rebuild. If you have multiple crates you could use [cargo cranky](https://github.com/ericseppanen/cargo-cranky) instead of check / clippy